# How to give “Email does not exist” using this call back function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have already tried for "Already exists", but I need help for "Does not exist" instead of "Already exists" using same function.

login.php

```
public function email_exist($id) {
    $this->db->where('email', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('login');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message(__FUNCTION__, 'Already exist!');
        ;
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

If the email does not exist in the database, it has to show email does not exists in login page.

Answer (score 0):

**Check row exist**

Get row having email id, if not get data then return true;

```
public function email_exist($id) {
    $this->db->where('email', $id);
    $exist = $this->db->get('login')->row_array();
    if (!$exist) {
        return true;
    } 
}
```

But if you want a login scenario, then you can do as

```
public function email_exist($id) {
        $this->db->where('email', $id);
        $exist = $this->db->get('login')->row_array();
        if ($exist) {
           // START SESSION HERE
            return true;
        } else {
           // give email not exist message 
           return false;
        }
    }
```

if you login via ajax, then you can `echo "email_not_exist"` from controller

Comment: Its Working and I have changed it to :    public function email_exist($id) {
        $this->db->where('email', $id);
            $query = $this->db->get('login');
    if (!$query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message(__FUNCTION__, 'Does not exist!');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
//controller

function email_exist($email) {
        $this->load->model('model_name');
        $emailArray = $this->model_name->get_data_by_email($email);
        if (!empty($emailArray)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message("validate_email", "Email already exists ");
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

//model 
 function get_data_by_email($email) {
        return $this->db->where('email', $email)->get('login)->row_array();
    }
```